# Is Viber using TCP for VoIP?

Tags: networking, firewall, voip, viber

I'm currently on a guest WiFi where all ports except those for surfing the web (80, 443, 8080) and mailing (25, 110, 143, 465, 587, 993, 995) are blocked (3128 seems to be working too).

I tried to place a Facetime call on my iPhone but that didn't work, which made me assume that UDP is blocked too.

However, the Viber app was able to successfully connect and start a video call with decent quality/lag.

My question is now, is Viber using TCP for VoIP or how is this possible?

Comment: More then likely; Yes; FaceTime likely just uses it also but on a port that's blocked.  Viber likely just uses 80/443.  Skype also uses TCP but its underline protocol isn't published

Comment: Did your "blocked ports" test actually include UDP? If you only tested TCP ports, that says nothing about UDP availability, as the two protocols have their own port assignments and can be filtered independently. (Some firewalls offer a "TCP/UDP" macro but that's all it is.)

Comment: @grawity That's a good point. I didn't find a test server to test it against for UDP, so my test was limited to TCP (via portquiz.net)

Comment: @Ramhound See my answer for the ports Viber actually requires (more than just 80/443).

Answer (score 0):

#### Is Viber using TCP for VoIP?

Viber is using UPD and not TCP for VoIP traffic. TCP is used for Text Messaging.

Viber uses [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) (and [SRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol) when encrypted). RTP is mostly implemented on UDP as it is a real time protocol.

> The RTP stream of the audio or audio/video call is converted to SRTP and encrypted via Salsa20 algorithm using the session key.

Source [Viber Encryption Overview](https://www.viber.com/en/security-overview)

The use of both TCP and UDP is confirmed in [Viber Communication Security unscramble the scrambled Contents](http://www.academia.edu/5717224/Viber_Communication_Security_unscramble_the_scrambled_Contents), which used `tcpdump` to generate `.pcap` files to analyse the Viber data traffic:

> This seemed like a good starting point to get some results so we filtered the data to get a one way voice stream using the following command:
>
> ```
> tshark -r long-call.pcap -w long-call-oneway.pcap udp.dstport == 5243
> ```
>
> Here we select only the UDP packets with the destination port for the Viber service so it is only originating voice traffic.
>
> ...
>
> Besides the voice calls that Viber enables the user to make, it also allows them to send and receive text messages. This functionality uses some **specialized tcp-based protocol to connect to the server
> and exchange messages**. Decoding this stream has not been a priority within this project and there wasn’t any time left to research this further.

---

#### What ports does Viber use?

> In order for Viber Desktop to run on your computer, the following
> ports must be open for all addresses for both TCP and UDP:
>
> - 5242
> - 4244
> - 5243
> - 9785
> - 80
> - 443

Source [Opening ports for Viber Desktop](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1506350-opening-ports-for-viber-desktop)

Comment: So in other words, if UDP is blocked, no call should be possible and therefore UDP has to be working on the guest network on the ports Viber is using?

Comment: I think that is correct.  See updated answer with a list of required ports (both UDP and TCP are required on these ports).

Comment: But my successful call also means that Viber only requires 80 or 443 (or both) to work (for the TCP side at least). From what I read on the linked websites it seems that RTP is *usually* implemented on UDP but that doesn't rule out that Viber doesn't have a backup-service on TCP. I would test for UDP ports but I don't know any target to test against with nmap.

Comment: Try a [UDP Speed Test](http://testmy.net/hoststats/udp) - that should tell you if UDP is blocked :)

Comment: uPNP may be open allowing to use some UDP ports.

Comment: @comfreak Answer updated with new info. It seems that UDP is used for VoIP traffic and TCP for Text Messaging.

Comment: @comfreak Do you need more help? If this was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to upvote/accept it.

Comment: The UDP speed test doesn't really work for me, the website seems to not load completely. But another thing I tried in the meantime is to start a Wireshark capture and tried to connect to my IPsec VPN (which fails) and I get an ICMP response telling me "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)". The same thing happens more obviously when I try to run a traceroute, where the gateway at the guest WiFi's router tells me the same error "!X". So my assumption is that straight UDP doesn't work. The router's uPNP port seems to filtered too.

Comment: @comfreak What OS did you traceroute from? Windows doesn't use UDP for traceroute. It uses ICMP (Linux does use UDP).

Comment: @DavidPostill I was using macOS which does use UDP. If I test with ICMP packets, the traceroute works.

Comment: @comfreak Then I'm out of ideas. I suggest you ask Viber for a definitive answer.